Using extern template with class constructors
I'm trying to use extern template to reduce compilation times in my project. In particular, I want to minimise the instantiations of a class constructor.
Here is a sample code:
#include <iostream>

namespace Hello {

class Test {
    template<typename T>
    Test(T& t) {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};
}

extern template Hello::Test::Test<int>(int&);

When compiling this Clang, I get the following error:
> <source>:13:30: error: qualified reference to 'Test' is a constructor name rather than a type in this context
     13 | extern template Hello::Test::Test<int>(int&);
>       |                              ^
 <source>:13:34: error: expected unqualified-id
     13 | extern template Hello::Test::Test<int>(int&);
>       |                                  ^
 2 errors generated. Compiler returned: 1

However, it compiles fine with GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/61M3zxsE3.
What's going on here?

It should be w/o explicit setting the template parameters, the 4th form of Function template instantiation.

Explicit instantiation of a constructor cannot use a template parameter list (syntax (1)), which is also never necessary because they can be deduced (syntax (2)).

extern template Hello::Test::Test(int&);

This is because constructor template parameters can't be explicitly set, they can only be deduced from the arguments.
int n = 0;
auto t1 = Hello::Test<int>(n);  // error
auto t2 = Hello::Test(n);       // ok
Test<int> t3(n);                // error
Test t4(n);                     // ok


So is GCC incorrect here?

Yes, it's incorrect, it often has standard unconforming extensions.
